# how to fetch data from db and display in views

Tags: yii

I am new to yii framework.I have just create an app and I want to fetch data from DB based on some condition and then display that in views .For this I have tried few things in my controller :

```
    if(isset($_GET['sku']))
    {
              $sku=$_GET['sku'];
          $data=Products::model()->findAll("sku=$sku");
    }
    $this->render('checkout',array(
        'data'=>$data,
    ));
```

and when in my views i try to print data as :

> print_r($data);

I shows me a complex array , but i do not want that.
The thing which i want is I can get an array from controllers which includes the data return by query based on some condition and in my views using foreach i can display them according to my need.

So please suggest me some good ways of fetching data from db and can display them in my views.

Thanks   !!

Comment: You should at least read the basics of how to work with ActiveRecords. We can not learn Yii for you :). `findAll()` returns an array of ActiveRecord objects as described here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar

Comment: Thanks  Michael Härtl  , the link you suggested me helps me a lot and now I can fetch and save data . thanks once again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view use something like this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->fieldname); ?>
```

Or better, use the Gii code generator to build your CRUD functions, and you will see several good examples for how to build these functions.  Here is a link to a very good tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app

Comment: if this worked out for you, please mark thequestion answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use DAO instead Active Record

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE sku = ".Yii::app()->request->getParam('sku', 0);
$data = Yii::app()->db
        ->createCommand($sql)
        ->queryAll();

$this->render('checkout',array(
    'data'=>$data,
));
```

You should have `db` component in config file(ex. config/main.php)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao